# Values are same on debug, but not in if statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement, radio-button

I have a problem with if statement. Two values - strings, one declared in class by arrow and another declared by radiobutton.gettext(). In debuging i can read values of both var. and they are same, but if statement says they are different. 
Do you have any idea why is this happening?

**Debuger:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYrMV.jpg

Getting **rbAnswer** :

```
private String mChoices [][] = {
    /* #8 */        {"razgovor između pomoraca u karanteni i njihovih obitelji", "za osobno razmatranje i razgovor s duhovnikom"," "," "},
```

}

...

```
public String getChoice1(int a) {
    String choice0 = mChoices[a][0];
    return choice0;
}


public String getChoice2(int a) {
    String choice1 = mChoices[a][1];
    return choice1;
}
```

...

```
rbGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        String rbAnswer;

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.radiobtn1)
                rbAnswer = "" + rb1.getText();
            else if (checkedId == R.id.radiobtn2)
                rbAnswer =  "" +  rb2.getText();
            else if (checkedId == R.id.radiobtn3)
                rbAnswer = "" + rb3.getText();
            else if (checkedId == R.id.radiobtn4)
                rbAnswer = "" + rb4.getText();

            tTEST.setText(rbAnswer);
            if (rbAnswer == mAnswer) {
                varScoreTrue = varScoreTrue + 1;
                updateScore(varScoreTrue);
                obavijestTocno();
                updateQuestion();

            } else {
                varScoreFlase = varScoreFlase + 1;
                updateScore(varScoreFlase);
                obavijestKrivo();
                updateQuestion();
            }



        }

    });
```

Declaring **mAnswer**:

```
private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {

            ...

        /* #8 */        "za osobno razmatranje i razgovor s duhovnikom",


            ...
}
```

...

```
public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
    String answer = mCorrectAnswers[a];
    return answer;
}
```

...

```
mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
```

Comment: They are different. You use `.equals` to compare Strings, not `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu're doing wrong comparation.

Change:

```
rbAnswer == mAnswer
```

to

```
rbAnswer.equals(mAnswer)
```